# How to implement middleware for Swagger in compojure-api for converting schemas from kabab-case to camelCase

Tags: clojure, swagger, compojure-api, reitit

Application uses kabab-case key formatting for schema like below

```
(s/defschema User
  {:first-name                                 s/Str
   :last-name                                  s/Str})
```

But for swagger docs I want the schema in camelCase like below

```
(s/defschema User
  {:firstName                                 s/Str
   :lastName                                  s/Str})
```

Is there any way of implementing middleware for swagger so that I can transform schema from kabab-case to camelCase? Please suggest how can I achieve this.

My current code looks like this below for dynamic swagger docs generation for the api

```
(api {:format   {:formats       [:transit-json :json]
                 :params-opts   {:transit-json {:handlers transit/transit-read-handlers}}
                 :response-opts {:transit-json {:handlers transit/transit-write-handlers}}}
          :coercion coercions/default-coercions
          :swagger  {:ui   "/swagger"
                     :spec "/swagger.json"
                     :data {:info {:title "API Docs"}
                            :securityDefinitions
                                      {:api_key
                                       {:type "apiKey"
                                        :name "Authorization"
                                        :in   "header"}}
                            :tags     [{:name "User" :description "/api/v1/user"}]
                            :consumes ["application/json"]
                            :produces ["application/json"]}
                      }
          :api      {:invalid-routes-fn (constantly nil)}}
         (create-api-routes web-server-config :middleware default-middleware))
```

I am using swagger provided by compojure-api for routing.

We can implement my requirement using [reitit](https://github.com/metosin/reitit) and there is also a sample project [rest-api using reitit](https://github.com/tzafrirben/rest-api-reitit/blob/master/src/rest_api_reitit/server.clj) how to achieve this. But I want to achieve similar thing using compojure-api as i don't want to upgrade to new library for routing now.

Comment: Are you asking how to make middleware, or how to map one structure to another with different keys, or how to translate a word from camelCase to kebab-case and back? Answers to those questions might be more readily at hand.

Comment: I want to know where can I implement the logic to transform the keys